# Very hard to work around continuous latent code in InfoGAN

Tags: deep-learning

It is always a pleasure to work with InfoGAN as it can unsupervisedly decode the structure of the data. The discrete latent worked very well for me to categorize different trajectories. However, I've been a little frustrated recently as I'm trying to implement the continuous latent code.

I first try the mnist example given by the original InfoGAN paper, and it worked fine as the first continuous latent code represents the leaning angle and the second continuous latent represents the width. However, when I tried it on my own toy data sets,(something like
[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXAMm.jpg), [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNRTM.jpg)) nothing really works out. I expect to see continuous variation on my output, but they are instead completely random, like the latent code doesn't work at all.

I use convolutional and deconvolutional networks to discriminate and generate samples and follow the same manner for the discrete latent code as in the original OPENAI implementation. My treatment towards the continuous latent code is a little different, I model the continuous latent code distribution directly as uniform distribution(instead of gaussian distribution in the OPENAI implementation) and use MSE to measure its distance to the input code.

```
loss_c_cont = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(c_cont_fake - c_cont), 1))
```

I think about it for a while, but don't think it could cause a huge difference as the gaussian distribution distance also mainly takes into account the square of epsilon = (x_var - mean).

```
return tf.reduce_sum(
        - 0.5 * np.log(2 * np.pi) - tf.log(stddev + TINY) - 0.5 * tf.square(epsilon),
        reduction_indices=1,
    )
```

I don't know if I actually noticed all the subtle tricks in the OPENAI implementation. But I just wonder if anybody has some experience with the continuous latent code implementation in InfoGAN, or even just the training of InfoGAN in general.

I'd really welcome all your thoughts!

Comment: Without a [mcve] this question is too broad for Stackoverflow.

Comment: OK, let me post some.

Comment: Also, these other Stackexchange sites: https://stats.stackexchange.com/ and https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ are more specialized on such topics

Comment: OK thanks, I think I could move my post there.